# AWS Athena fails when there are empty files in S3

Tags: hive, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-athena

I have a data pipeline that copies data partitioned by date. Sometimes there is no data for a day. The datapipeline creates a 0 bytes csv file. When I run an Athena query for this date it fails instead of returning 0 results. The error I get is
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Unexpected end of input stream

How can I avoid this. I understand one way is to never create files with empty data but I could never figure out how to do that in a data pipeline. Is there anything I can tweak in Athena so that it does not fail this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command after your data has been copied by data pipeline.

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

This would recover \ update the partitions to the Athena catalog. 
It can be the last step in your data pipeline. Before you actually make it part of your pipeline, try executing it in the Athena Query console and verify if it resolves the issue.

Comment: - this command gives error: ```line 1:1: mismatched input 'msck' expecting {'(', 'select', 'desc', 'using', 'with', 'values', 'create', 'table', 'insert', 'delete', 'describe', 'grant', 'revoke', 'explain', 'show', 'use', 'drop', 'alter', 'set', 'reset', 'start', 'commit', 'rollback', 'call', 'prepare', 'deallocate', 'execute'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: b89789c6-05ba-4de2-9915-6c3b534212a2)```